# Binding Element using ng-repeat and push service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I'm using Ionic framework. I have a question on binding the element from JS using push and ng-repeat element. I don't see the binding value on the HTML, not sure if this is the correct way of implementation.

Concept of this Application:
To use Google places search API for JS to find store nearby the device location and display the name and address of the shop on the html page. 
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- remember to add your Google Maps API key! -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="LocationCtrl">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">My Location</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content scroll="false">

        <div class="list card">
          <div class="item item-input">
               Result:
              <div ng-repeat="result in db">
                  {{result.name}},{{result.formatted_address}}</div></div>
          <div class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Coordinates:</span>
            {{coords.latitude}}, {{coords.longitude}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('LocationCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform) {

    $scope.db = [];
    var map;
    var infowindow;
function showMap() {

        var pyromont = { lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{ 
            center: pyromont,
            zoom: 12
            });    
        var request = {
    location: pyromont,
    radius: 500,
    type: ['store']
  };
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
    };


        function callback(result, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          $scope.db.push(result);
          console.log($scope.db);
      }
};
})
```

So As you could see here on JS code, when i try to push the array values from result to db, and in html with ng-repeat, when i try to read the binded values I couldn't read anything on result. But on logging the value of db, i see a array with 20 variables on console window, which i exactly what i got from the placesservice.js when i saw on the chrome developer tools.
I'm not sure what is the issue, Kindly have a look and Let me know if i missed to include any parameter/ service.Looking forward to hear your comments.
Regards
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
$scope.db.push.apply($scope.db, result);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!